# Turkish Character Problem on mailing

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email, characters, html-email

I am using Woocommerce plugin for my e-commerce site.
For mailing I've installed Postman SMTP.

I could not handle with Turkish characters on ongoing e-mails. Such characters "Şşğ..." on mail body I see "???" chars.
I've tried to change charset of html mail to utf-8 by overriding email-header.php but no luck.
I am also checking sent e-mail from my inbox. It's charset seems as utf-8.

Another point, Turkish characters are seemed supported on e-mail subject,

How could I get rid of this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on 
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/9348

It was not about the Turkish characters, it is more generic
Removing utf8_decode() function in function getUnifiedHtml() -line 530- resolved the problem.